# What ports are SSL in Microsoft ISA server?

Tags: ssl, isa-server

I was wondering what ports Microsoft ISA Server designates as being SSL by default?

I know the standard 443, but i'm trying to find out if there are others and i don't have administrative access to the ISA server in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check your IIS for SSL ports, because you can configure and change SSL ports on IIS manager , you can see the ssl ports which are configured differently.

Comment: Thank you, instead of bugging you for which are configured by default I'll just use a random IIS 6 to check myself.